# How can I show typing keyboard in record screen

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, keyboard

When I record the screen on a Mac, how can I show keyboard typing in the same image (as shown below)?

[image]

Is there particular screen recording software or settings that will do this?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I also use Screenflow, but there are also a few standalone apps for that like [Keycastr](https://github.com/keycastr/keycastr) and [Mouseposé](http://boinx.com/mousepose/overview/).

Answer (score 24):

You could try showing the on-screen keyboard:

[image: on-screen keyboard]

This is obviously a very different aesthetic than shown the OP's screenshot, but if it meets your needs, here's how you do it:

## Instructions for macOS High Sierra (and probably others)

- **Menu** > **System Preferences…** > **Keyboard**
- ☑️Show keyboard and emoji viewers in menu bar
  [image: Show keyboard and emoji viewers in menu bar]
- If you don't see a flag in your menu bar yet:

  - Switch to the **Input Sources** tab
  - ☑️Show input menu in menu bar
    [image: Show input menu in menu bar]
- Click on the input menu & select **Show Keyboard Viewer**
  [image: Show Keyboard Viewer]

Comment: I don't see this in the dropdown.  I see this: https://imgur.com/Filzgfb  The trick is, I need to check both those boxes or it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 16):

I’m recording lots of tutorial videos / screencasts for my YouTube channel and was very unhappy with existing solutions for displaying keystrokes on macOS. So I’ve made my own keystroke app:

**Download**: https://ixeau.com/keystroke-pro/

**Video**: https://youtu.be/3koqaw99uKA (30 seconds)

**Features:**

- Animated keystrokes look gorgeous in light and dark
- Works great with macOS Mojave
- Individual designed keys for common `ISO` and `ANSI` keyboard layouts
- Localized for 23 languages

[image]

Comment: Only for mac 10.14+ (Mojave and later) - just a note for other non-Mojave users ;)

Comment: Definitely worth it! Updated link: https://ixeau.com/keystroke-pro/

Answer (score 9):

I believe this is a part of [Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/), which costs $99, but does have a trial available.

OS X does have a limited ability to do this, but it only shows modifier keys, like Shift, Ctrl, Command, etc. If you're interested in that, it's in System Preferences > Universal Access, under the Keyboard tab. Turn sticky keys on, and then push "Display pressed keys on screen". I don't think that's what you want, but you can check that out as well.