# Free presentation helper that shows keystrokes

Tags: software-recommendation, keyboard

Are there any free standalone presentation tools that shows which keys are pressed on screen?

[KeyCastr](https://github.com/sdeken/keycastr) is not available as build for users without Xcode. Only a community fork (git://github.com/bignerdranch/keycastr.git) is working on OS X 10.7 (Lion) and 10.8 (Mountain Lion).

[Mouseposé](http://www.boinx.com/mousepose/overview/) is commercial.

---

Related to the Windows 7 Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529329

Comment: This is a valid question, but don't forget that MousePosé is only $5. Sometimes you have to pay for good software.

Comment: Other related questions [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52618/how-can-i-show-typing-keyboard-in-record-screen/52636) and at [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/407334/how-can-i-see-a-visual-overlay-of-shortcut-keys-ive-pressed/407340).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X comes with such a tool.

To activate it, you should go in `System Preferences` --> `Keyboard` and select `Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar`, see screenshot below.
[image]

Then in the top menu bar, ext to the clock, you should have a new icon.[image]

Click on it and select `Show Keyboard Viewer`, now each time you press a key, the Keyboard viewer will briefly display that key. You will have something similar to this:
[image]

I hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Great alternative to the apps mentioned in the question!

Comment: yes, nice one.. Not exactly what I'm looking for but indeed a good, free, on-every-mac-available alternative. It's just too big to let it enabled per default for presentations purposes.

Comment: I use it personally a lot to find "hidden" characters. On my Mac keyboard, characters such as |\{}[], which I use a lot as developer and terminal freak, are not shown/printed. Using this tool, I can quickly spot them by pressing one of the changer keys (like Alt, etc.)