# App to show keyboard shortcuts being used real-time

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts-app

In some screen recording software you can choose to show what keyboard shortcuts are being used or just keys in general that are being pressed. These show up as a semi-transparent dialog typically on the screen with the keys being pressed inside that.

When I'm pair programming it would be really helpful for someone that's looking at my screen in real-time to know what shortcuts I'm using. Is there any app that allows me to display this live on my own screen or anything that records the shortcuts I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Keycastr](https://github.com/keycastr/keycastr) (Open-source, free)
- [Mouseposé](https://boinx.com/mousepose/) (Annual subscription, additional mouse features, free trial available)
- [Keystroke Pro](https://ixeau.com/apps/keystroke-pro/) (Paid, no subscription, light/dark themes, focus on design, free trial available)

You can alternatively show the on-screen keyboard but this is extraneous for my use case.

---

**Note:** These apps are all listed in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52618/how-can-i-show-typing-keyboard-in-record-screen/52637#52637) which specifically refers to screen recording.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to work with my partner and show them the on screen keyboard viewer and talk / slow down when they are new. Also, empowering them to interrupt you, asking if you’re good to proceed and asking if they want to review any steps, they’ll let you know when they get the key shortcuts and then you can close the keyboard viewer.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52637/5472

Also, why not have them do the typing. Coach, guide them and then they’ll know the shortcuts and why to use them.

All of the answers in the linked question work for recordings, but live programming isn’t the same as needing to record them so large IMO.

Comment: While I do think those are good practices, they aren't a solution. In certain times, it's good to stay in flow and not have to ask what that keyboard shortcut is. Other times, the pair doesn't even know that a keyboard shortcut was used at all so it's helpful to display it.

Comment: @BradyDowling Yes. And worse if there is no menu item, you can’t expose a key shortcut easily without this sort of HUD tool.